# Fail to connect to database after change IP

Tags: java, android, mysql

I know this probably be one of the popular questions but my situation seems to a bit different. I used to connect my android device to mysql using IP 192.168.1.x, everything worked fine. But when I connect to other network with IP 192.168.0.x, the connection fails, I din change anything on my code and the WampServer is online too. How could this happens?

> 04-22 16:45:46.150 6533-6578/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.5 (port 80) after 15000ms

Comment: Change port number for 192.168.0.5 IP. Then it will work.

Comment: use 8081 instead of 80

Comment: @SkyWalker what port should i use? as i know standard port for http normally is 80 and 8080, i try both but it's not working

Comment: use 8081 instead of 8080

Comment: @SkyWalker it's not working even i try with 8081, still have other possible issue behind this?

Answer (score 0):

In your Android code you should update your Current IP Address instead of old IP Address

Comment: sorry not to mention previously but i have done tat too, is that anythg done with port?

Comment: For testing , paste your new url to your browser. and then check it's works or not. also check your port details

Comment: it's working in browser but not when connect using my android device, i change different port but the problem still there

Comment: Mobile data / wifi is Connected or not? if yes, then try localhost instead of ip address